# Unit Testing Custom React Hooks in TypeScript using Jest and @testing-library/react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs

I have a custom hook that takes a product id and toggles with `value (boolean)` and `toggle` as the returns. I'm trying to write a unit test for it, following the example [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/test-custom-hooks-using-react-hooks-testing-library-a3a37031a9be), but I'm getting TypeScript type-mismatch errors (the example I'm following isn't typescripted).

**Custom Hook:**

```
export default function useToggle(id: number): [boolean, () => void] {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = localStorage.getItem(ITEMS);
      const all = data ? JSON.parse(data) : {};
      setValue(!!all[id]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('items localStorage get error', error);
      setValue(false);
      localStorage.removeItem(ITEMS);
    }
  }, [id]);

  function toggle() {
    try {
      const data = localStorage.getItem(ITEMS);
      const all = data ? JSON?.parse(data) : {};
      all[id] = !all[id];
      localStorage.setItem(ITEMS, JSON.stringify(all));

      setValue(v => !v);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('items localStorage set error', error);
    }
  }

  return [value, toggle];
}
```

**Test in progress:**

```
describe('useToggle', () => {
  it('returns value and toggle', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useToggle(1));
    const { value, toggle }: [boolean, () => void] = result.current;

    expect(value).toBe(false);
    expect(setValue).toBeDefined();

  });
});
```

**Error:**
Where I'm defining `value` and `toggle`, I'm getting `Property 'value' does not exist on type '[boolean, () => void]'.` and `Property 'toggle' does not exist on type '[boolean, () => void]'.`

Am I setting up the type definition incorrectly or is something else going wrong? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array. Therefor you have to destruct using `[ value, toggleLike, toggleLike]` and not `{ value, toggleLike}`.

```
describe('useLikes', () => {
  it('returns value and toggleLike', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useLikes(1));
    const [ value, toggleLike ]: [boolean, () => void] = result.current;

    expect(value).toBe(false);
    expect(setValue).toBeDefined();

  });
});
```